# Toggle an input

Tags: c#, windows-7, toggle, slimdx, gamepad

I am using SlimDX to use my Xbox 360 controller and I would like a way of when pressing a button on the controller the state changes to on and stays on but when I press it again it becomes off. Sort of like a toggle. But I have been unable to do one so far(Just a beginner really).

Thanks for any help.
Thomas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a `bool` to determine if the button is toggled on or off.  You will also need to know the gamepad's previous state, so the `bool` won't toggle all the time, just because you keep pressing the button.

```
bool myCommand = false; // declare the bool
GamePadState oldState; // you need to know the previous state of your gamepad

public void Update()
{
    if (GamePad.GetState().KeyPressed == /*key*/ && oldState.KeyPressed != /*key*/)
        myCommand = !myCommand;
    oldState = GamePad.GetState();
}
```

Keep in mind, that you may need to use something other than `GamePad` or `GamePadState`, as this is merely pseudo-code

Comment: @Thomas don't forget to upvote/accept if the answer was satisfactory ;)