# SlimDX Controller, Toggle

Tags: c#, toggle, slimdx

I tried to impliment a toggle into the Left D-pad but it doesn't work

```
private void SerialTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        bool PreviousCarHeadlights = false;

        if (controls.DPad.Left & !PreviousCarHeadlights)
        {
            CarHeadlightsCheckBox.Checked = !CarHeadlightsCheckBox.Checked;
            PreviousCarHeadlights = !PreviousCarHeadlights;
        }
    }
```

Please could someone look at this and help.

Comment: It is but it doesn't work now. Don't know what happened.

Answer (score 1):

Go through your code sequentially, the answer is quite obvious:

First, you set `PreviousCarHeadlights` to `false`, next you check whether `controls.DPad.Left` is pressed AND `PreviousCarHeadlights` is `false` (which it is, since you just set it to `false`).

In other words: your headlights will always toggle as long as your DPad is pressed regardless of its previous state, since `if (!PreviousCarHeadlights)` is a tautology (meaning, it will always resolve to `true`)

The answer given here: [Toggle an input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14959638/toggle-an-input) is all you'll ever need when dealing with toggle. Keeping track of your gamepad's previous state means that you'll always know which button was pressed previously. It is a lot better than keeping track of many `bool` for each button that can be toggled.